# How does the SQL Server engine store and handle [n]varchar(MAX) vs [n]varchar(n)?

Tags: sql-server

I am under the impression that SQL Server will store nvarchar(n) values in memory locations which can be overwritten while nvarchar(max) will be  pointers to a reference type variable, hence it being immutable.

Am I correct or wrong?

I have looked for this in documentation but not found it so far.

Thanks!

Comment: What you're describing does sound a lot like what @DavidG is referencing below - when data gets pushed out of a page. But that is not dependent on the data type it's dependent on the actual data. You're definitely mixing up programming and databases here. If you want to make the most of SQL Server you should focus more on set based programming and understanding indexes, statistics, and the query planner

Comment: Well... I do understand all of that :) Been working with SQL Server since... I think... 1998? Gee, it's been a long, long time!!! I am just trying to figure out how it's working under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

Storing 50 characters in an `NVARCHAR(50)` column and storing 50 characters in an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column are actually no different at all. Both values are stored within the row. The problem comes when the total size of the row exceeds the page size of SQL Server which is 8060 bytes (actually 8192 bytes but there's some overhead per page.) This means at around 4000 characters (unicode data is 2 bytes per character) the data needs to be stored out of the row. This means it's stored elsewhere and only a 24 byte remnant remains which is effectively an address to where the data is being kept.

[Here is some info regarding the "overflow" storage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: So by storing elsewhere, do I understand that, in this instance, what we have stored is a pointer to an immutable reference type? Opposed to "within the row"?

Comment: I think yo uare thinking about this too much as a programmer, I'm not sure you can compare it to an immutable reference type.

Comment: Well what can I say? I am a programmer.

Comment: Not to worr, so am I! :)